# upgrade pig in hd insight emulator

Tags: azure, emulation, azure-hdinsight

The latest version of HD insight emulator has pig 9.3 is there any way to update it to the latest i.e. pig 12.x.

I want to use the newer functions like rank etc which seem to be available only in the new release.

Answer (score 0):

There is PIG 12.1 in the newest HDInsight 3.1 preview along with Hortonworks HDP 2.1.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-component-versioning/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info... 
But I was looking for the option in the emulator...
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-get-started-emulator/

Guess it's not available..